# Hazy password example question - connect to sandbox?

Tags: mobile

Hi I set up tomgersic's [mobile SDK example "HazyPassword"](https://github.com/tomgersic/HazyPassword) on macBook.

How do I update it to have it connect to a sandbox instead? The readme file says "- A Settings screen that allows the user to pick an instance (ie Production or Sandbox) or force a logout the next time the app reopens."

I don't see this setting page when I run it from the xCode simulator. Is it possible to change that in the code? I couldn't find it referenced in bootconfig.js.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Check in the iOS system settings in the emulator / on the device.

Apps that use the iOS Mobile SDK from Salesforce have an entry in there (towards the bottom) which includes a setting for which login endpoint to use. It'll look something like this:

[image]

Comment: This also worked. I couldn't see the app under settings for iPhone. But it displays for iPad. I changed it there. Thanks!

Comment: Not angling for points, but part of SFSE is marking the correct answer as accepted so that others know the deal in the future!

Answer (score 1):

In xcode click on the project(top level element) then 'Info' then update `SFDCOAuthLoginHost` to test.salesforce.com

You can also get to this under Supporting Files by editing PROJECTNAME-Info.plist.

Comment: Hi I changed the SFDCOAuthLoginHost to test.salesforce.com and did a re-build. Then run. But the app still updates my developer org instead. I also updated the remoteAccessConsumerKey to that of remote app on the sandbox and also the callback URL: https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/success. When I checked the log, it still says trying to connect to login.database.com "SFAuthCoordinator:authenticate:authenticating as "developer org consumer key" with refresh token on "https://login.database.com", which are the old values from my developer org. How do I clear out the cache?

Comment: Can you logout of the app? or go to the iOS Simulator menu and select Reset Content and Settings.

Comment: There is the Reset Content and Settings in iOS Simulator menu. Not sure why I didn't see that. Now I'm able to connect to a sandbox. Thanks!

Comment: @MobileDeveloper cool, glad to help.